# Saving prices with different languages

Tags: c#, decimal

In our application you can switch the default language. We have also prices for products. I am wondering what the best way is to persist those prices into the database.

We in Holland use the comma as a decimal seperator, but the Americans use the dot as a decimal seperator.

In my form I have two textboxes: one for whole numbers and one for decimals. I now have the situation that in the first textbox I have the value 2 and in the other I have 00 (so I have 2 euro and 0 cent). When I save this to the database, it stores 200.00.

What do I have to do to store 2.00 instead of 200.00?

Comment: This is a `CultureInfo` thing... you can save the `CultureInfo` of your user, and display for his/ her cultrure.  But you're not *storing* it differently, you're just *displaying* it differently.

Comment: I agree with CultureInfo method. But if you insist on saving the prices differently, you can use multi-columns for the different currency in the database. You also need another column to indicate that user's preference.

Comment: You've obviously have a problem parsing the data from the text boxes. BUT, your third paragraph makes little sense. If you have the whole value and the decimals **in different text boxes**, then what is keeping you from storing them properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We now store the amount as cents. When retrieving the amount from the database we divide this amount by 100 with the culture info of the user.